# Add JFileChooser to Android studio

Tags: java, android, swing, android-studio, jfilechooser

I am new to Android studio  and want to create a simple GUI with it. I want to add the JFileChooser, however it cannot be found in the palette, even though it's a Swing component. I searched through my components, but there is no file chooser.

How can I add the JFileChooser to Android studion ?

I can `import java.awt.*; import javax.swing.*;` but I cannot find JFileChooser –

Comment: Swing is not part of android sdk. You have to create a view on your own.

Comment: yes I want to know how to download or import it @Shriram

Comment: No you can't..import awt component in android

Comment: No I can import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*; but I cannot find JFileChooser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java AWT classes contain native code, so unless someone ports that native code to Android, you can't. And, they won't port it,  Android has its own graphics libraries (android.graphics).
And the hierarchy of JFileChooser inherits from awt package.

```
java.lang.Object
    java.awt.Component
        java.awt.Container
            javax.swing.JComponent
                javax.swing.JFileChooser
```

So if you really want it to import JFilechooser you should import some sort of native code first to Android.
Better to use Android libraries instead.

Comment: Do u have any idea how to open filedialoge on menuitem click please @Shriman

Comment: Hope this links helps http://www.scorchworks.com/Blog/simple-file-dialog-for-android-applications/